# How could I call a User defined function from spark sql queries in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to call a function from my spark sql queries. I have tried udf but I don't know how to manipulate it.
Here is the scenario:

```
# my python function example

def sum(effdate, trandate):
  sum=effdate+trandate
  return sum
```

and my spark sql query is like:

```
spark.sql("select sum(cm.effdate, cm.trandate)as totalsum, name from CMLEdG cm ....").show()
```

These lines are not my code but I am stating it as an example. How could I  call my sum function inside spark.sql(sql queries) for getting a result?
Could you please kindly suggest me any link or any comment compatible with pyspark?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Kalyan

Answer (score 4):

You just need to register your function as UDF:

```
from spark.sql.types import IntegerType()

# my python function example
def sum(effdate, trandate):
  sum=effdate+trandate
  return sum

spark.udf("sum", sum, IntegerType())
spark.sql("select sum(cm.effdate, cm.trandate)as totalsum, name from CMLEdG cm....").show()
```

Comment: `spark.udf.register()` worked for me (pyspark v3.3.1).

Answer (score 3):

Check this

```
    >>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
    >>> sqlContext.udf.register("stringLengthInt", lambda x: len(x), IntegerType())
    >>> sqlContext.sql("SELECT stringLengthInt('test')").collect()
    [Row(_c0=4)]
```